# Match on a column but only if another column contains a string

Tags: excel

I've got the following table in Excel, which is basically a list of phone number and messages received from those number.

```
Phone    Message
1234     REGR8547
1234     FWVR8.5
8479     REGR1154
8479     DBGW0
```

I've got another sheet which just contains a list of phone numbers (no duplicates). On this second sheet, I want to basically transpose the data so that it looks something like this:

```
Phone    REG        FWV        DBG
1234     REGR8547   FWVR8.5
8479     REGR1154              DBGW0
```

So essentially, in each column on the new table, I want to match the phone number, but also check to see if the message contains a string. So, for the REG column, I want to include the message if Phone = 1234 and Message startswith REG.

Although I can do this manually, I will be getting more and more source data in the original table, and so ideally, I just want to be able to paste new data into the source table and have the second table automatically update.

How can I do that in Excel?

Answer (score 2):

You may use this formula in the pic. Please use

> **Ctrl-Shift-Enter**

to enter it in the first output cell, then copy across and down.

[image: Formulas all on same sheet]

Look at the setup i have used in the pic, and adjust your cell references accordingly.

In particular:

1) Adjust your first argument of the match function to whereever your output table is

2) If your output formula is on a different sheet as you said it would be in your case, then please enter the full sheet reference to the lookup ranges.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$5,MATCH($E2&F$1&"*",'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$5&'Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$5,0)),"")
```

Comment: I saw your answer and decided to learn something about array formulas. I'll be on the lookout for a future opportunity to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your profile and determined that you could handle a VBA macro as a solution. I think this should get you started.

I made these two assumptions:
1) The original data starts in Row 1, Col A.
2) All original duplicate phone numbers are in consecutive rows. They can be sorted in any order, but they have to be together like you have them.

This code goes down the original phone number list and creates a new row in column D every time the phone number changes. It uses the MID function to look for strings that start with REG or FWV or DBG, and then writes the strings to the appropriate row.

You can adjust it to write to another worksheet if you want. You can also make it more flexible to handle more situations. You can step through in debug mode and watch it fill in the cells on the spreadsheet.

```
Sub PhoneText()

Dim Wbk As Workbook

Set Wbk = ActiveWorkbook

Dim currentPhone As String

Dim numOriginalRows As Integer
Dim numNewRows As Long

numNewRows = 1 'Skip the header row.


Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Activate
numOriginalRows = Wbk.Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count


Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(1, 4).Value = "Phone"
Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(1, 5).Value = "REG"
Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(1, 6).Value = "FWV"
Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(1, 7).Value = "DBG"


For x = 2 To numOriginalRows + 1 'start at 2 because of header.

    If (currentPhone <> Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(x, 1).Value) Then
        currentPhone = Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(x, 1).Value
        numNewRows = numNewRows + 1
        Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(numNewRows, 4).Value = currentPhone
    End If

    If (Mid(Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(x, 2).Value, 1, 3) = "REG") Then
       Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(numNewRows, 5).Value = Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(x, 2).Value
    ElseIf (Mid(Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(x, 2).Value, 1, 3) = "FWV") Then
        Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(numNewRows, 6).Value = Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(x, 2).Value
    ElseIf (Mid(Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(x, 2).Value, 1, 3) = "DBG") Then
        Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(numNewRows, 7).Value = Worksheets("PhoneNumbers").Cells(x, 2).Value
    Else
        ' Some error message here.
    End If



Next x

End Sub
```